# Displaying branch descriptions in magit

Tags: magit

The release notes for magit 2.1.0 state "Branch descriptions can now be displayed in the refs or status buffer". However, I can't find these features documented in the info pages. I am using magit 20150701.1326.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some buffers, including status and refs buffers, Magit [now uses customizable hooks](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Section-Hooks.html#Section-hooks). Such hook variables are named `magit-{*}-sections-hook`. All functions that insert sections are named `magit-insert-WHAT`. To add functions to section hook variables use `magit-add-section-hook`. It offers a little more control over where exactly the function is inserted, than plain `add-hook`. So try this:

```
(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook
                        'magit-insert-branch-description
                        nil t)
```

and/or

```
(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-refs-sections-hook
                        'magit-insert-branch-description)
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to replace the existing header (`magit-insert-head-header`) with the branch description header, instead of inserting it.

Comment: Right. I thought it was a section intended as a header line, but it's actually a full, collapsible section. I have adjusted the answer.

Comment: That was quick :)